# Priority queue in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, priority-queue, query-performance

I'm currently in the process of building a web crawler in C#. To queue the URLs which have yet to be crawled I use SQL Server. It works pretty fast, but it starts getting really large over time which slows down my stored procedures.

```
CREATE TABLE PriorityQueue
(
ID int IDENTITY(0,1) PRIMARY KEY,
absolute_url varchar (400),
depth int,
priorty int,
domain_host varchar (255),
);

CREATE INDEX queueItem ON PriorityQueue(absolute_url);
CREATE INDEX queueHost ON PriorityQueue(domain_host);
```

This is the table I use for my queue. The priority numbers from 1 to 5 with 1 being the highest priority. As you can see I also use indexes for my stored procedures down below.

**Procedure for adding new items to the queue:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.Enqueue
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Enqueue(@absolute_url varchar(255), @depth int, @priorty int, @host varchar(255))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [WebshopCrawler].[dbo].[PriorityQueue] (absolute_url, depth, priorty, domain_host) VALUES (@absolute_url, @depth, @priorty, @host);
END
GO
```

**Procedure for getting the item with the highest priority:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.Dequeue
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Dequeue
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT top 1 absolute_url, depth, priorty
    FROM [WebshopCrawler].[dbo].[PriorityQueue]
    WHERE priorty = (SELECT MIN(priorty) FROM [WebshopCrawler].[dbo].[PriorityQueue])
END
GO
```

This one gets realy slow with larger data.

**Procedure to delete the dequeued item:**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dbo.RemoveFromQueue
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RemoveFromQueue(@absolute_url varchar(400))
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE 
    FROM [WebshopCrawler].[dbo].[PriorityQueue]
    WHERE absolute_url = @absolute_url
END
GO
```

I tried using lots of different indexes, but nothing seemed to make the procedures go any faster. I hope someone has an idea on how to improve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/). The important issues:

- You must organize the table according to the dequeue strategy. Primary key in IDENTITY makes absolutely no sense. Use a clustered index based on priority and dequeue order.
- You must dequeue atomically in a single statement, use `DELETE ... OUTPUT ...`

So it should be something along these lines:

```
CREATE TABLE PriorityQueue
(
  priority int not null,
  enqueue_time datetime not null default GETUTCDATE(),
  absolute_url varchar (8000) not null,
  depth int not null,
  domain_host varchar (255) not null,
);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX PriorityQueueCdx on PriorityQueue(priority DESC, enqueue_time);

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Dequeue
AS
BEGIN
    with cte as (
       SELECT top 1 absolute_url, depth, priority
       FROM [PriorityQueue] with (rowlock, readpast)
       ORDER BY priority DESC, enqueue_time)
     DELETE FROM cte
         OUTPUT DELETED.*;
END
GO
```

Comment: `default GETUTCDATE()` >> best give that constraint a name rather than have SQL Server assign to it a random one. I know it's just illustration =) but people might blindly copy it thinking it's good practice not to name constraints.

Comment: Second, there's no guaranteed sorting if rows are added with the same `enqueue_time`, which would happen for fast inserts or when you have bulk inserts. That would be counter to the idea of a queue.

Comment: TT. You are right, I've tried the above and it works alright but urls can be inserted at the same time 'cause of multithreading.

Comment: If two entries are added at the exact same time, which of them should be dequeued first? My point is that if they are added at the exakt same time then there is nothing else than randomness to dictate which is first to be dequeued. They are equal in ordering.

Comment: Datetime has resolution of .000, .003 and .007. vales in between are rounded to the nearest possible of those values. A row inserted at ~.001 and ~.000 are both stored as ~.000. See where I'm getting at? Sorry, the queue decribed in thus answer is broken